# Hide svg used for gradient

Tags: html, css, svg, gradient

I need to give gradients for several svg objects in separate divs, for that I created a global svg for defining only gradients. The defined svg takes the height and width. If I reduce the width and height to zero then the gradient does not working. Is there any way to hide the svg without affecting the gradient.

the code for creating svg gradient and svg is

```
<svg id="asd">
  <linearGradient id="linear" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="100%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
    <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0" />
   <stop stop-color="#f3b65a" offset="0.5" />
   <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="1" />
 </linearGradient>
</svg>
<svg>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="600" height="200" fill="url(#linear)" />
</svg>
```

The link for a particular problem is

https://jsfiddle.net/6f45bx02/

Comment: what do you mean by "hide the svg without affecting the gradient?" There are two svg's I see in your code. I assume you mean try to hide the svg with the id of `asd`?

Comment: @Jhecht yup i need to hide the first svg from the page. If i hide that then the gradient is not working in the second svg

Comment: have you thought about just positioning that off screen ?

Comment: @Jhecht means positioning it absolute and give top and left a huge negative value??

Comment: yes, that is what I am referring to.

Comment: Suhail, please look at my answer that was first. You are making this too much work. There is a very easy method and I have the working demo below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add these to your gradient svg style rules

```
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
```

It will hide your svg, and take that svg element out of your page flow so it will not occupy any pixels on your page

Comment: Why not display:none which makes the subtree not even processed?

Comment: @DanielB. Then you can't reference that gradient svg because the browser "ignores" `display:none` elements

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Some browsers do. Some browser do not. So not a good suggestion.

Comment: @DanielB. Because a good developer tries to make his apps work across all browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can always use. This hides the element but keeps the positioning.

```
visibility:hidden
```

```css
#asd{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- SVG syntax -->
<svg id="asd">
  <linearGradient id="linear" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="100%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
    <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0" />
    <stop stop-color="#f3b65a" offset="0.5" />
    <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="1" />
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
<svg>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="600" height="200" fill="url(#linear)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel G. Blázquez figured out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562818/gradients-hidden-using-svg-symbols) you can set width and height to "0" and display to "block". Thus you achieve the same effect as with display="none", but gradient will remain visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

- pick one of your SVGs like the first one (doesn't matter)
- add to it definitions group: `<defs></defs>`
- describe in there all of your gradients
- then let all other SVGs you have in the same page to just    refer
  those gradients.

This way you don't have to do those weird workarounds...